# Razor .NET is not recognizing code script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in my view. Inside of a `for` statement, I want to group every 4 items in a parent `div`. `If(counter == 0)`,  I render the parent `div`, then I render four items and then if it's the last of the group of 4 items, I close the parent `div`.

However, it looks like razor is expecting me to close the parent `div` in the first `if`. It appears Razor is not smart enough to know the parent closing tag is inside the second if some lines below, or maybe I'm missing something. Any thoughts to resolve this?

```
 @{int counter = 0; }
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserManagedRoles.Count; i++){
      string roleName = Model.UserManagedRoles[i].Name.Replace(" ", "").Trim();
      string id = string.Format("chk{0}", roleName);

      if (counter == 0)
      {
           <div  class="rowCapture divUserRoles">
      }

      <div class="hzStackSmall">
      <input type="checkbox" id="@id" name="@id" value="@roleName" />@Model.UserManagedRoles[i].Name</div>

      if(counter == 3 || i == Model.UserManagedRoles.Count) {
           </div>
      }

      counter++;
      if (counter == 4)
      {
           counter = 0;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `@: <div class="hzStackSmall">` to print HTML code with the razor engine. Will this help?

I strongly recommend [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) tutorial from ScottGu's Blog about the razor engine.

```
 @{int counter = 0; }

 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserManagedRoles.Count; i++)
 {
    string roleName = Model.UserManagedRoles[i].Name.Replace(" ", "").Trim();
    string id = string.Format("chk{0}", roleName);

    if (counter == 0)
    {
       @:<div  class="rowCapture divUserRoles">
    }

    @:<div class="hzStackSmall">
    @:<input type="checkbox" id="@id" name="@id" value="@roleName" />@Model.UserManagedRoles[i].Name</div>

    if(counter == 3 || i == Model.UserManagedRoles.Count) {
       @:</div>
    }

    counter++;
    if (counter == 4)
    {
       counter = 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: @tarkanboy, happy to help. Can you mark my response(or any other) as an answer?

Comment: @cacho - this happens way too often.